# How to disable showing printer prompt in NightmareJs

Tags: node.js, pdf-generation, electron, nightmare

I am trying to download one of the PDF from my server using the Nightmarejs. I have install it via node module as:-

```
npm install nightmare
```

and write down the following code:-

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');

var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false})

nightmare
  .goto(url) // url of my site
  .size()
  .type('[name=email]', '')
  .type('[name=email]', 'test@gmail.com')
  .type('[name=password]', 'test')
  .click('#signInSubmit')
   .wait(2000)
  .pdf("test.pdf")
  .evaluate(function () {
 return document

  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
 console.log(result)  
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });
```

it will save the PDF file into my current directory but as i also set electron to false it will not shown the browser but it will show the printer setting prompt to print i just not need that prompt to be appear . i just want to know how can i achieve that. As i google it will give me to set silent as true for that but i don't know where should i set that silent true option.

```
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false})
```

I mean how and where do i configure the electron setting in nightmare js script file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the site calling `window.print()`?  If so, you could *probably* get away with defining a [custom preload script](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/#custom-preload-script) based on the [default preload script](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/blob/master/lib/preload.js) and adding an override for the print function.  That should prevent the print dialog from appearing.  From the hip:

```
window.print = function(){
  //shows the print call in the DEBUG log
  __nightmare.ipc.send('log', 'print called');
}
```